# Using Git in Visual Studio, how do I navigate repository files?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I installed [Visual Studio Tools for Git](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c) in Visual Studio 2012, which looks just like the Git support Visual Studio 2013 has out of the box.  I went to "Connect to Team Projects" and used "Add" under Local Git Repositories to add an existing Git repository.  When I open it, I see no option to browse the code:

[image]

The Solution Explorer pane is empty, too.

How do I navigate the Git repository files within Visual Studio?  Isn't there a "Source Control Explorer" for Git like there is for TFVC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There actually isn't a way to navigate your Git repo inside VS yet. If you're on the RTM you can open any solution that is inside the repo from the Team Explorer homepage. Other than that you need to use Windows Explorer or something else for now.

I've been told that this is high on their priority list, so I would expect to see it soon (probably 2013.1 I would guess).

Comment: Also, it appears that if you open a project inside a Git repo, it automatically figures out it's in Git and adds context menu items like View History and Commit to the Solution Explorer.  Is my assessment correct?

Comment: Yes, it should detect that and alter Team Explorer to reflect.

Comment: Hah, I guess 2013.1 was a little optimistic... 2015.1 maybe?!

Comment: Hah, nope. It's infuriating that Microsoft has made Git a first class citizen everywhere except in Visual Studio. And given that you cannot use TFVC in VS Code, nobody knows the direction Microsoft is taking and a lot of teams are on the fence about which version control system to use. I think the safest bet is to use git with a GUI outside Visual Studio.

Comment: @AndrewClear 2016 here, is there ever going to be a repo explorer in Visual Studio?

Comment: At this point I kind of want to edit out the "high priority" bit... but the comedic value of it remaining is pretty high

Comment: 8 years later - still nope. This is why tools that _do_ let you browse a repo, including _browse-repo-as-of-commit-id_ are worth the hundreds of dollars they command.