# Git with Visual Studio Source Control Explorer available yet?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, github

we set up Git as version control system (we used tfs before). Now the source control explorer is not available anymore.

I found this thread from 2013:
[Using Git in Visual Studio, how do I navigate repository files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839256/using-git-in-visual-studio-how-do-i-navigate-repository-files)

It's 2015 now and I cannot find any info from late 2014 or 2015. Does anybody know something new?

Thanks

Comment: While it would be nice to have a git source control explorer embedded in VS, it would be sufficient (for my own immediate selfish purposes) with some sort of stand-alone application that allows me to browse files/folders in branches I have not currently checked out.

Answer (score 6):

VS2015 still does not have a file browser for Git projects.  They do have a list of *.sln files that can be opened within a Git repo.  If you have say a "ReadMe.txt" at the root level of the repo though, you still need to open it in explorer or command line and modify it (either by adding to VS or elsewhere), then the file will show up in pending.

In VS2012, there was an add in called "Mindscape File Explorer" that added a file explorer.  You could set the root directory to your projects folder and save you from leaving VisualStudio.

Apparently no one at Microsoft cares about solving this problem since it's been around for years now.  Seems like it would be an easy win to just show all files at the project root level in either the solution tab or a new project view tab.

Comment: Nothing changed in VS "15" Preview, would it make a difference if I installed Git for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio "15" Preview has an "Open Folder" feature that let's you load up any folder in the Solution Explorer but it's not connected with Source Control, you have to do it manually after you've connected with the repository in Team Explorer but it's better than nothing.

You can right-click the file to access History, Commit, Compare with unmodified, Undo, Go to git changes... etc

Comment: Thanks Jonney, it's a start!