# Do we have Git source control explorer in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio

We get source control explorer for the TFS source control model, and it is productive.

Do we get a similar source control explorer for Git in Visual Studio 2017?

If we do have it, how do I navigate to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git with Visual Studio Source Control Explorer available yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064078/git-with-visual-studio-source-control-explorer-available-yet)

Comment: @glennsl Not duplicate. VS 2017 supposed to have improved Git support. The article you pointed relates to VS 2015 which is an older product. I was concern that there might be a tendency to generalize the topic, but VS2017 has an upgraded Git support.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short, no, there is no built-in UI support for Git in Visual Studio 2017.

Alternatively, you can try the following extensions based on your source control setup.

In Visual Studio, select *Tools* → *Extensions and Updates*, select *Online* on the left pane, search for one of the following in the search bar in the top right:

*Bitbucket* → install *Visual Studio Bitbucket Extension*

*GitHub* → Install *GitHub Extension for Visual Studio*

*Git* → Install *Easy Git Integration Tools*

The first two do a good job of providing UI controls to work with source control as they relate to Bitbucket or GitHub in a similar fashion to regular TFS integration (that you may be familiar with). I haven't tried the third one myself, and I'm not sure what that one is like.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So it is safe to assume that still VS 2017 does not have built-in Git source control explorer and the tool is available for TFS source control model only? If so, please update the answer, so I can mark it.

Comment: I'm not too sure where you heard that VS 2017 is supposed to have built in support, but to my knowledge, it doesn't. Our office has been using VS 2017 for about 4 months now and have either had to use command-line git, or the bitbucket extension in visual studio.

Comment: The question is "Do we have .... ?" I guess the correct answer is "No". Yous answer explains the alternatives. I suggest changing the answer to "No, there is no built-in support, but here are a few alternatives:". That way it helps others when they google the question. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 4):

Please see the Solution Explorer - Folder View. This can be accessed from Solution Explorer (open with CTRL+W, S), then by clicking the Solutions and Folders toggle button. In Visual Studio 2017, it looks like this:

[image: Screen snippet of Solution Explorer - Folder View and View Toggle button]

Though it's not a 1:1 capability of the Team Foundation Source Control Explorer view, it does have the ability to view files in the local repo, open, view history, etc.

Comment: As you mentioned, this shows the local repository. We can't find out what is happening in the remote repository.

Comment: I downvoted because this shows you the project filesystem - it doesn't show you the _repository filesystem_, nor does it let you view the _point-in-time_ directory structure and file-contents of a repo for a given commit. Other tools can do this (Source Tree has "Show Repository at Revision"; GitKraken has "View all files"), so why can't VS do this despite supporting Git for 8+ years now? The old TFS experience from 2008 was far, far superior to the Git experience today.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio does not currently have Source Control Explorer for Git repositories. You might consider voting on this User Voice item to help the product team prioritize features:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/4178754-visual-studio-tools-for-git-extension-microsoft-g

Comment: +1 for the uservoice URL to improve support for this request (still relevant since 2013-2017). Thanks @jamill !!!

Comment: @jamill - When clicking on your link, I get "This site is not currently active"

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019, open the folder for the work space using "File->Open->Folder...". The solution explorer, via "View->Solution Explorer", should display all the files which you can then right click to view history and other GIT operations.

Comment: Hello -- I believe the was asking about VS 2017

Comment: I downvoted because this still doesn't answer the question being asked. The steps in this answer will only show you the _project structure_, not the _repo structure_. While the Folder view shows you your local filesystem it isn't the same as a real git repo browser - nor does it let you see the repo's point-in-time state (not without doing an entire `checkout`). Also "GIT" is not an initialism, it should never be written in all-caps - doing so just betrays this answer's author's ignorance of git.