# How do I compare a local file with the one on Git in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way in VisualStudio 2015 to get the Source Control Explorer to work with Git. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839256/using-git-in-visual-studio-how-do-i-navigate-repository-files) says it was not working in VS2012 but I can't find anything about VS2015.

I need to compare a local file with the version on Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source Control Explorer only works with TFVC - there is not a corresponding Source Control Explorer for Git. You might want to vote on this user voice suggestion for it to be included in the future:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/4178754-visual-studio-tools-for-git-extension-microsoft-g

You can view local changes with the Changes page, or compare versions from the history page.

Comment: Well that's not good :(. Where is the history page? The View, Other Windows, History page just says not TFS.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to view history. The history of current branch can be accessed via most Git related Team Explorer pages through the "Actions" link. It is also accessible from branch indicator at bottom right of Visual Studio. The history of a branch can be accessed from Branches Team Explorer page. The history of a file can be accessed through context menu in in solution explorer, or in an open file.I can edit the answer with some visuals if there is still confusion.

Comment: Could you please add some visuals?